# npm install peerDependencies for newer version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am new for nodejs. I have package.json like this

```
{
  ...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "some-lib-that-use-old-react": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xx/somelib.git",
    "other-lib-that-use-old-react": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xx/other.git"
  },
  ...
}
```

After I run `npm install` I get project tree like this

```
node_modules
|
|__some-lib-that-use-old-react
|__other-lib-that-use-old-react
|__react
```

I use peerDependencies because do not need `react` in `some lib` and `other lib`

(It work right that I expected)

But the version of react is not `16.0.0`. It is old version from other lib.

Can I get react 16.0.0 with `peerDependencies` ?

I want one place of lib that I will use `peerDependencies` instead of `dependencies`.

I already try with `npm-shrinkwrap.json` like this

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": { "version": "16.0.0", "from": "react@16.0.0" }
  }
}
```

But It is not work right with `This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but npm-shrinkwrap.json was generated for lockfileVersion@0.`

I use `npm 5.5.1 & node 8.9.3`. And do not have `package-lock.json` before install.

Thank everyone for come to help.

**Update 1** I change OS from mac to windows but It does not work, too. `npm cache clean --force` not help, too.

**Update 2** In package.json of react after `npm i` It look like this

```
{
  "_from": "react@old-version",
  "_id": "react@old-version",
  ...
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/some-lib-that-use-old-react",
    "/other-lib-that-use-old-react"
  ],
  ...
  "version": "old-version"
}
```

Comment: Try to delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm i` again

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077306/npm-unmet-peer-dependency-error-cant-install-braintree/48077896#48077896

Comment: Sorry I try again and follow link but It do not work again. I try both mac and windows but same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From NPM document

> One piece of advice: peer dependency requirements, unlike those for
> regular dependencies, should be lenient. You should not lock your peer
> dependencies down to specific patch versions. It would be really
> annoying if one Chai plugin peer-depended on Chai 1.4.1, while another
> depended on Chai 1.5.0, simply because the authors were lazy and
> didn't spend the time figuring out the actual minimum version of Chai
> they are compatible with.

Please understand peer dependencies support oldest version because the authors were lazy and didn't spend the time figuring out the actual minimum version of Chai they are compatible with.

See more : https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

---

[Update on 2020-10-16]

Now in 2020.

NPM Version 7.0.0 make peerDependencies better than before and solve my old problem.

Please you check with this below link for more information.

https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0025-install-peer-deps.md/