# @angular/cdk@5.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@~5.1.1 but none is installed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, datepicker

> @angular/cdk@5.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@~5.1.1 but none
>   is installed

I'm having this error when I try to install angular date picker form the NPM console.

> npm install angular2-material-datepicker

I believe due to this whenever I run my project there will always be problems. For example the following error is coming out from the angulr2materialdatepicker

> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   ./node_modules/angular2-material-datepicker/src/calendar.ts:78:5 
>       TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof Calendar' has no index signature.

How do I fix this peer issue?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48077896/4515361

Comment: Looks like it's an error with the dependency itself: https://github.com/koleary94/Angular-2-Datepicker/pull/100

Answer (score 0):

## First question

Isn't it obvious? You should probably understand what the peer dependency error means: it's to show that one of your dependencies (in this case, `@angular/cdk`) **requires** another dependency (in this case, `@angular/common`) in order to serve its function.

Anyways, to solve the peer dependency problem, run this on your application's directory (in your terminal):

NPM v5 (it should automatically include the dependency in your `package.json`):

```bash
npm i @angular/common
```

Below NPM v5:

```bash
npm i --save @angular/common
```

## Second question

As for your second question:

- <del>Is it caused by the dependency? Or is it caused by code? Or is it caused by a typo? Please include your code in your question in order for others to see what's wrong.</del> EDIT: Looks like it's an issue and a PR has been filed [here](https://github.com/koleary94/Angular-2-Datepicker/pull/100)
- Next: Please do not post multiple questions in one question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, appreciate it!

when i try to install 'npm install @angular/common',
there is an error:

@angular/cdk@5.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@~5.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

but when I install angular core, the same error comes again

Comment: You meant you typed in `npm install @angular/core` and got the error?

Comment: yes,  there errors are never ending... is there a tool where one can just fix all these peer dependencies? it's so frustrating

Comment: @user1034912 Just wondering but what's your npm version? You can get it by typing `npm -v`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is a `cut-down` version of my `package.json` file

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/cdk": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/common": "5.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "5.1.1",
        "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/material": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-server": "5.0.3"
    },
```

Basically you have to finesse with the version numbers.